Class names like 'Workflows' or 'WorkflowTemplates' not exposed
I'm encountering an issue in Azure Functions where class names like Workflows or WorkflowTemplates seem to be causing problems. Specifically, functions within these classes are not being exposed or recognized by Azure Functions. However, when I move these functions to a different class, they work as expected.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, and is there a solution or workaround? I'm curious about why specific class names might cause functions to not be exposed in Azure Functions.
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
[RequestHttpHeader("Authorization", isRequired: true)]
public class Workflows
{
    private readonly IPhoenixLogger _logger;

    public Workflows(IPhoenixLogger logger)
    {        
        _logger = logger;        
    }
 
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Workflow>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
    [Function("GetWorkflows")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunGetWorkflows(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Workflows")] HttpRequest req
    )
    {
        return await Middleware.Run(async () => await GetWorkflows(req), req, _logger);
    }
}


HttpRequest: Get /api/Workflows - Not found 404

[RequestHttpHeader("Authorization", isRequired: true)]
public class WorkflowFunctions
{
    private readonly IPhoenixLogger _logger;

    public WorkflowFunctions(IPhoenixLogger logger)
    {        
        _logger = logger;        
    }
 
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Workflow>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
    [Function("GetWorkflows")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunGetWorkflows(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Workflows")] HttpRequest req
    )
    {
        return await Middleware.Run(async () => await GetWorkflows(req), req, _logger);
    }
}


HttpRequest: Get /api/Workflows - OK 200


can you please share the .csproj file for both the cases

There is no such restriction in providing a certain class name for Azure function. It accepts all the class names including Workflows and WorkflowTemplates too.

For testing purpose, I have below code in Workflows.cs class.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace _78470050
{
    public class Workflows
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Workflows> _logger;

        public Workflows(ILogger<Workflows> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("GetWorkflows")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Workflow>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RunGetWorkflows([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "Workflows")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            return await Middleware.Run(async () => await GetWorkflows(req), req, _logger);
        }

        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetWorkflows(HttpRequest req)
        {
            var workflows = new List<Workflow>
        {
            new Workflow { Id = 1, Name = "Workflow 1" },
            new Workflow { Id = 2, Name = "Workflow 2" },
        };

            return new OkObjectResult(workflows);
        }
    }

    public class Workflow
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 }

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78470050</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am able to get the expected response.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-05-13T08:22:02.827Z] Found C:\Users\******\78470050\78470050\78470050.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-13T08:22:05.843Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 24468) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-05-13T08:22:05.885Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        GetWorkflows: [GET] http://localhost:7280/api/Workflows

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-13T08:22:10.970Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-13T08:22:20.536Z] Executing 'Functions.GetWorkflows' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=564778a5-b570-4ae1-8208-4ebfcb9dd053)
[2024-05-13T08:22:20.851Z] Middleware: Pre-processing logic executed.
[2024-05-13T08:22:20.851Z] Middleware: Post-processing logic executed.
[2024-05-13T08:22:20.858Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[_78470050.Workflow, 78470050, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
[2024-05-13T08:22:20.952Z] Executed 'Functions.GetWorkflows' (Succeeded, Id=564778a5-b570-4ae1-8208-4ebfcb9dd053, Duration=479ms)

